# How can i import yaml file to use it in gnu make file?

Tags: makefile, yaml, gnu-make

How can I import a list from YAML file, to use it in a GNU make file.
The list contains a few c source files as shown below.

```
---
- file1.c
- file2.c
- file3.c
- file4.c
...
```

Comment: Well, what do you want to use it _for_?

Comment: In my project workspace ,i have mixes programming files(c,c++ and python) at different directory location .I use gnu make tool to control the generation of executables as well as  coping python file to install target.If i add more file to my project, every time i need to make changes to make file.To avoid that i thought of creating a ymal config file and if i can import the config file to gnu make file, then i should have a generic make file that should not be touched when i add more file to my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why it's easier to add the new source file to a yaml file than to just add it to the makefile.

But the direct answer to your question is, there's no already-existing support for yaml files in make.  You'd have to write a set of shell commands or a script that could parse out the content then run it from your makefile with something like:

```
SOURCES := $(shell parsemy foo.yaml)
```

(implementation of the `parsemy` script left as an exercise for the reader).

If you think the makefile is too complicated to edit you can put the source definition in a separate makefile and `include` it:

```
$ cat sources.mk
SOURCES = \
    foo.c \
    bar.c \
    biz.c

$ cat makefile
include sources.mk

... do other stuff ...
```